# Orbeon autocomplete - keep what user entered (even if not matched to suggestions)

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, orbeon

I'm using **Orbeon forms - Autocomplete** component and calling an external service to provide me with list of suggestions, based on what user has entered.

The requirement I have is to enable the user to **keep what he has already entered**, even if service cannot find appropriate match.

However, I have the problem that currently the service gets called when I move to another field (or when i simply click in and out of the autocomplete field), and it returns me the *empty string* or *null* which automatically gets populated as autocomplete field value (blank).

Do you have an idea how can I solve this? Since Orbeon autocomplete gets rendered as multiple fields, I'm not sure how JS logic is behind it.

Thanks,
Lazar

**[Update-workaround]** Check reply to @avernet answer - workaround: Replaced existing (external) service call, with one going to my back-end controller, which executes the call the original, external service with search parameter the user provided. If controller receives back blank value as a suggestion (implying that there are no matches), it creates a empty XML structure which is the one Autocomplete expects, but with search parameter the user has entered as a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This use case isn't covered by the autocomplete control. You can think of the autocomplete as a selection control, say like the dropdown, but only for cases where the list of possible values is too long to show as-is, or even to load in the browser as-is, so you instead want to show just part of it, based on a "search" the user is doing.

It seems that what you're looking for would be an autocomplete that supports `selection="open"`. Even if this isn't exactly what you're looking for, we've implemented [open selection for radio boxes](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/2394), and are shooting to release this in 4.11.

Comment: Hi @avernet, thanks for quick response as always. I actually found some workaround that appears to be working.

I've replaced existing (external) service call, with one going to my back-end controller, which executes the call the original, external service with search parameter the user provided. If controller receives back blank value as a suggestion (implying that there are no matches), it creates a empty XML structure which is the one Autocomplete expects, but with search parameter the user has entered as a value.

Not the ideal solution, but it does the job, at least for now.

Comment: @LazarDeretic Ah, yes, this is a very good way to do it! And now that you mention it, I'd swear I suggested this technique to someone else in the past; I should have thought about it when answering your question in the first place :).